# How to correct this jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

In another question, someone turned me onto this method of writing a jQuery `.append()`, but I can't seem to get it to work. The console returns an error, "Unexpected string" but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Not working:

```
$(".create-form").submit(function(event){
    var title = $("#story-name").val();
    copy = $("#story-content").val();
    $(".storyboard").append(
        $("<li/>", className: "story").html(
            $("<span/>", className: "story-count") +
            $("<span/>", className: "story-title-input", content: title)));
});
```

I've also tried with a comma in place of the "+" and `.append()` instead of `.html()` on the first appended element. I can get it to work by writing out all the html but this feels like a cleaner method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sure you're missing `{` and `}` for your json initialization.

```
$(".create-form").submit(function(event){
    var title = $("#story-name").val();
    copy = $("#story-content").val();
    $(".storyboard").append(
        $("<li/>", { className: "story" }).html(
            $("<span/>", { className: "story-count" }) +
            $("<span/>", { className: "story-title-input", content: title } )));
});
```

Then I would replace this

```
$("<li/>", { className: "story" }).html(
   $("<span/>", { className: "story-count" }) +
   $("<span/>", { className: "story-title-input", content: title } )));
```

by

```
$("<li/>", { className: "story" })
   .append($("<span/>", { "class": "story-count" }))
   .append($("<span/>", { "class": "story-title-input", text: title } ));
```

Comment: Okay, I haven't tried your last method, but on my first try I was wrapping the attributes in braces. That didn't seem to help. So maybe it's the last part that will wrap it all together.

Comment: Originally, I had a lot more elements before I stripped it down and it looked like: <code>$(cont).append(
     $("<li/>", {className: "story", id: "s-" + index++}).append(
      $("<div/>", {className: "new-item"}).append(
       $("<a/>", {href: "", className: "launch-task", content: "Create a task"})
       $("<input/>", {type: "text", className: "new-item-title", value: "something"})
       $("<div/>", {className: "drops waiting"}).append(
        $("div/>", {className: "drops working"}).append(
         $("div/>", {className: "drops finished"}))))));</code>

Comment: So that one probably had some other errors in it that made it incorrect. But regardless, I'll try your suggestion. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So your method worked. I was missing a couple other things like className didn't appear to be right even though a previous example I saw had it. It created a className attribute, which of course, doesn't work. I also needed .text() on the final span with content: title since again, content isn't an attribute I needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This code isn't valid:

```
, className: 'story'
```

What you're probably looking for is an object literal, try wrapping the arguments to `$('...')` in `{}` like so:

```
$(".create-form").submit(function(event){
    var title = $("#story-name").val();
    copy = $("#story-content").val();
    $(".storyboard").append(
        $("<li/>", {className: "story"}).html(
            $("<span/>", {className: "story-count"}) +
            $("<span/>", {className: "story-title-input", content: title})));
});
```

Comment: Your method is working. However, the returned result is not what I expected. I'm now getting [object Object][object Object] as a result and then it flashes, then disappears...but it is trying to append it to the right place at least and appears valid.

Comment: I had a couple of things wrong in the code above and so I think that's what was causing the latest errors. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more readable, and a much better way to do it :

```
$('.create-form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $('#story-name').val(),
        copy  = $("#story-content").val(),
        li    = $('<li />',   {'class': 'story'}),
        span1 = $('<span />', {'class': 'story-count'}),
        span2 = $('<span />', {'class': 'story-title-input', text: title});

    $(".storyboard").append( li.append(span1, span2) );
});
```

you'll need to use objects for the elements properties

Comment: I did use this method first, but I decided I didn't need to use them again so setting them as vars wasn't necessary in my opinion. For sure, if I was going to reuse these I would make use of this method. Do you say it is better because of opinion or because of a standard? No offense, I'm seriously just asking since I'm learning js right now. I will admit I do see your method a lot and I was using it before trying this new way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion I guess.

Comment: And I did of course fix all the errors, was wondering if anyone else would notice the content and className attributes  :) ...

Comment: And I did not of course notice...lol. I guess you noticed my comments on the other answers. I only noticed after it wasn't rendering any text and saw it was adding a content attribute and className attribute, both of which I didn't want. I was keeping className because in another question someone was arguing that className was jQuery API and the proper thing to do. I guess they were wrong in this case. I should have known since I knew from reading the docs on jQuery site that it basically takes those args and runs them through .attr(). alas, I did not until later.